# No existing transaction found for 'mandatory' after calling @Sheduled Method

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have 2 methods:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *")
@Transactional
public void myMethod() {

  //omited logic without calling repositories or different methods

  helper.import(new Client()); 
}
```

and

```
@Transactional
public void myMethod() {

  //omited logic without calling repositories or different methods

  helper.import(new Client()); 
}
```

One sheduled, one not.
They calling this method in another autowired component:

```
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
 MyObject import(Client client) {

     System.out.println("test");

     clientManager.findClient(client);

     //omited logic
}
```

Method `findClient(Client client)` in another autowired component:

```
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
 public Client findClient(Client client) {
     //omited logic
}
```

Expected behavior: Transaction created in `myMethod`, then calling `import` with Mandatory propagation transaction and then calling `findClient` with the same propagation. So, all logic executed in one transaction. And when i calling myMethod() without annotation @Sheduled all works fine.

But when it calls by @Sheduled annotation it falls in exception 
`org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: No existing transaction found for transaction marked with propagation 'mandatory'`
It falls after trying to call `clientManager.findClient(client);` in `import` method after successfull printing "test" which means (i think) transaction was created in `myMethod`.

I tried to delete @Transactional on `myMethod` and set it on `import` method, so, expected to creating transaction in `import` and call `findClient(client)` with mandatory propagation, but it results the same exception.

Please help. I need this sheduled behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that the method `MyObject import(Client client)` didn't have `public` modifier, thats why transaction was not created even the @Transactional annotation exists (my bad, sorry).